# What is causing “there is no current model” in my python program?

Tags: python, z3

I mean, I got some problem when I trying to get a solution with python z3:

```py
from z3 import *

encFlag = [522, 747, 630, 524, 618, 548, 629, 533]
L = [0x4c, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x45, 0x43, 0x54, 0x46, 0x7b]
s = Solver()
x = BitVec('x', 16)
c = 'a'
for i in range(8):
    var = BitVec(c, 16)
    an = BitVecVal(encFlag[i], 16)
    bn = BitVecVal(L[i], 16)
    s.add((an - x) ^ var == bn)
    c = chr(ord(c) + 1)
print(s)
```

s.check works well, but when I tried to get solution I got only error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Py3.10\lib\site-packages\z3\z3.py", line 7130, in model
    return ModelRef(Z3_solver_get_model(self.ctx.ref(), self.solver), self.ctx)
  File "D:\Python\Py3.10\lib\site-packages\z3\z3core.py", line 4065, in Z3_solver_get_model
    _elems.Check(a0)
  File "D:\Python\Py3.10\lib\site-packages\z3\z3core.py", line 1475, in Check
    raise self.Exception(self.get_error_message(ctx, err))
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: b'there is no current model'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 15, in <module>
    print(s.model())
  File "...", line 7132, in model
    raise Z3Exception("model is not available")
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: model is not available

Process finished with exit code 1
```

hlp plz

I tried this, but there is obviously no direct way to compare two elements in different list in z3

```
for i in range(8):
    var = BitVec(c, 8)
    s.add((encFlag[i]-x) ^ var == L[i])
    c = chr(ord(c)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your:

```py
print(s)
```

with:

```py
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

and then your original program prints:

```
sat
[c = 1723,
 a = 1733,
 e = 1706,
 x = 64385,
 h = 1775,
 b = 1827,
 g = 1714,
 d = 1742,
 f = 1783]
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Note that you can only call `s.model()` AFTER you call `s.check()`, provided that `check` returns `sat`. Otherwise you'll get the "model is not available" error.